# Outlier detection in multivariate data

Tags: r, outliers, boxplot, cooks-distance

I have a table with thirty variables and am interested in finding the outliers (rows). Assuming that my variables are independent I am hesitant whether I should use Cook's distance as it requires to define (y~x), while I am interested in outliers that are out of Boxplot's quantiles independently with other variables.

For example: If the outliers of the first variable (v1) are observation(obs):1,2,3. The outliers of the v2 are obs1,obs4, and the outliers of v3 are obs1,obs4 I would like to obtain the following summary including the counting of the outliers:

obs1 - 3 times

obs4 - 2 times

obs2 - 1 time

obs3 - 1 time

This way I want to explore if there are some obvious outliers.

Comment: Better try Mahalanobis distance, it is $\chi^2$-distributed . A multivariate outlier can be OK in any coordinate.

Comment: You will need a very large number of records to reliably identify outliers in a 30 dimensional space.

Comment: You can regularise the covariance matrix...it's not very reliable, but it's something

Comment: @GermanDemidov do you mind please to attach a link to the reference explaining the procedure?

Comment: Hmmm, is your data normally distributed? are you sure that one-class LDA (Mahalanobis distance) is suitable? How many samples do you have?

Comment: My data is not normally distributed (Wilk Shapiro test). I have 55 samples and all my variables are on the [0,1] scale. Thank you in advance!

Comment: OK, this is a presentation of general idea: https://stat.ethz.ch/education/semesters/ss2012/ams/slides/v2.2.pdf . You have quite large number of features for 55 samples. You can try to regularise you covariance matrix for LDA, there are a lot of ways to do it (for example: http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~tcai/paper/Block-Thresholding-Covariance-Matrix.pdf - block matrix, or you can manually regularise by thresholding, or use klaR package). But what I would recommend you for your situation - just make your covariance matrix diagonal (spcov package or just fill the diagonal with variances).

Comment: For high dimension and nonnormally distributed data, you might consider the Local Outlier Factor approach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_outlier_factor. There are R implementations available.